# Visualizing "interference" in Quantum Programs

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

I'd like to develop an intuition about interference in QC programs and was hopeful that some visualization vehicle (like the bloch sphere) would be available to assist in developing an intuition of that (in phase kickback for example). I've searched but didn't find anything suitable.

Is there any vehicles or frameworks, (or math techniques) that could be helpful?

Comment: Would measures of [quantum coherence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02439) (a quantitative way of studying quantum interference) suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awesome drag-and-drop quantum circuit visualization Quirk offers *some* kind of visualiztion, i.e., one can display the probabilities (amplitudes) and density matrices for every step.

E.g. in the implementation of Simon's algorithm below for the function $f(x) = f(x \oplus s), s=11$ one can see the interference after the application of the 2nd Hadamard gate. First, all basis states are equally likely, then inteference kicks in with the Hadamard and you end up with only $|00>$ or $|11>$.

[https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[1,1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22],[%22Chance2%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22],[%22Chance2%22],[%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22]]}](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D,%5B%22Chance2%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22Chance2%22%5D,%5B%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D)

Comment: This was one of the best I have come across - will definitely make a note of it. It appears Interference must be observed indirectly, and can only be observed by watching it's effects.